# Process Chromatography vs Solid Phase Extraction techniques

Tags: chromatography, extraction

Process Chromatography is typically performed by flowing eluent from the top to the bottom of the column. The standard method of solid phase extraction at industrial scale e.g. to extract natural products from botanicals,  is to flow from the bottom up. What is the advantage or rationale for this way of operating?

Comment: Are you looking at any physically built processes in particular? Any specifics you can share about the motivation for this question?

Comment: Unlike chromatography,  extraction removes material from the "column".  I believe this could reduce efficiency for bottom up flow, unless a fluidised bed effect comes into play. Top down means the botanicals would be more inclined to be under the effect of gravity i. e.  Giving a better "bed" as it shrinks vs bottom up. This is my hypothesis, with no direct evidence, so I wanted to seek wider knowledge